# Ajax Nested Tab Container is not displayed in IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have the below nested tab container. The Root tab container is not displayed in IE but display in Chrome.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <cc1:TabContainer ID="RootTabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <cc1:TabContainer ID="NestedTabContainer1" runat="server">
                    <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel12" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel12">
                    </cc1:TabPanel>
                </cc1:TabContainer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
        <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <cc1:TabContainer ID="NestedTabContainer2" runat="server">
                    <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel21" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel21">
                    </cc1:TabPanel>
                </cc1:TabContainer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </cc1:TabPanel>
    </cc1:TabContainer>
    </form>
```